# Definition for "cheese dome"

Tags: word-meaning

I want to write a definition for "cheese dome" for a flashcard. There are no definitions for this term in a dictionary, at least in the ones that are available online.

Does *A dome-like cover, often made of glass, for storing cheese.* sound adequate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, "cheese dome" is exactly right:

> **Consider using a Cheese Dome:** Cheese domes are a great way to store cheese.  They’re washable, reusable, and durable.  Cheese stored under a dome creates its own climate, ensuring proper humidity every time.  White mold or soft ripened cheeses and washed rind cheeses are ideal when stored unwrapped under a cheese dome. [Source](https://www.formaticum.com/blogs/cheese-paper-101/2809722-all-about-cheese-storage)

Not being familiar with the term, I would have assumed a "cheese dome" is a *dome*, made out of *cheese*.  Which sounds *delicious*, and is a *possible* meaning, but not the common meaning.  You learn something new every day, I guess.

Otherwise your definition sounds good.  I would just add "under" at the end:

> A dome-like cover, often made of glass, for storing cheese under.